# Azure Data Factory Automated publishing for continuous integration and delivery

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I’m following the new CICD guide for ADF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment-improvements
Looks like I'm missing files `credential` and `managedVirtualNetwork`. Do I need to set up authentication with the npm module and Azure packages?

Getting these errors:

```
LocalFileClientService: Unable to list files for: credential, error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/vsts/work/1/s/credential'
…
LocalFileClientService: Unable to list files for: managedVirtualNetwork, error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/vsts/work/1/s/managedVirtualNetwork'
…

ERROR === CmdApiApp: Failed to run resource validation. Error: {"stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'concept' of undefined\n    at Function.<anonymous> (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:1271:27040)\n    at /home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:16:2243\n    at Object.next (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:16:2348)\n    at o (/home/vsts/work/1/s/downloads/main.js:16:1087)","message":"Cannot read property 'concept' of undefined"}
…
error code ELIFECYCLE
error errno 1
error @ build: `node node_modules/@microsoft/azure-data-factory-utilities/lib/index "validate" "/home/vsts/work/1/s" "subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/xxxxxxxx”
error Exit status 1
error Failed at the @ build script.
error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
##[error]Error: Npm failed with return code: 1
```

Comment: Could you try running  `run build export` directly to see if the arm template can be exported?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT thanks, I also got similar errors running it locally ```npm run build export <rootFolder> <factoryId>```

Comment: You need to change the Node version when building ADF task to 14.X. Please refer to this answer it resolved mine. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72648923/559227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing `credential` and `managedVirtualNetwork` folders are not an issue. I am able to validate and export the ARM template even without having those folders.

I was able to reproduce the error with an incorrect ADF Resource ID. The leading `/` before 'subscriptions' is missing. Changing the Resource ID to  `/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/xxxxxxxx` should work.

Comment: thanks @abhishek. When I do "Validate All" option in your Git-enabled ADF to verify, I get "Your Factory has been validated. No errors were found."

Comment: @ManriqueVargas The error seems don't block the pipeline. If the template can be exported successfully you can just ignore the errors. You can [accept above answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked out.

Comment: This Git-enabled ADF UI deployment works, but my error occurs using the `npm` new CICD guide for ADF from Azure-DevOps (see link in original post), not from the UI. The module `npm run build export <rootFolder> <factoryId>` is not working. It is not generating the ARM template in Azure DevOps

Comment: @ManriqueVargas I created a testing pipeline following the link in original post. I got the similar error. But the template was exported successufully. see [here](https://imgur.com/OiuDeHZ)

Comment: I was now able to reproduce this error by using an invalid ADF Resource ID. Looking at your command, I can see that the leading `/` before 'subscriptions' is missing. Can you try again with the updated resource ID? `/subscriptions/xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/xxxxxxxx`

Comment: @ManriqueVargas can you check if the above solution works for you?

Comment: @ManriqueVargas I have updated my answer above. Do mark it as the accepted answer if it works for you.