# ADF CI Build Error: Command failed: node /home/shaadmin/myagent/_work/5/s/adf/build/downloads/main.js validate

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-pipelines-yaml

Our ADF CI Build (configured as per [Microsoft doc][1]) was working fine till yesterday. Suddenly it started failing with below error today:

> Command failed: node  /home/shaadmin/myagent/_work/5/s/adf/build/downloads/main.js validate

Can anyone please help to resolve issue?
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Data Factory CI npm validate step suddenly crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645716/azure-data-factory-ci-npm-validate-step-suddenly-crashing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your npm version in your CI yml file.
npm version should be 14.x.

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'
```